# Print the best match in the Python list, where each element is separated internally

Tags: python, regex, list, python-2.7, compare

I created a Python list based on elements in a file, i.e., when elements of `row[0]` are present in `row[3]`, append both the rows to list `'matches'` and vice versa, when elements of `row[3]` are in `row[0]`, append them to `'matches'`. The list looks like below

```
['Peripheral Blood Mononuclear Cells;peripheral blood mononuclear cells', 'Blood;peripheral blood mononuclear cells', 'Hispanic or Latino;hispanic', 'Black;black', 'Black;black', 'Asian;asian', 'Asian;asian', 'Asian;caucasian', 'caucasian;caucasian', 'caucasian;caucasian', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Seizure;seizures', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Abscess;abscess']
```

I'd like to print only the first output for each element or perfect match irrespective of the case like below:

```
['Peripheral Blood Mononuclear Cells;peripheral blood mononuclear', 'Hispanic or Latino;hispanic', 'Black;black', 'Asian;asian', 'caucasian;caucasian', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Abscess;abscess']
```

Here if you notice, each element of the list is separated by a `";"`. I'm trying to take that as a standard and compare. I want only the first occurrence of each element based on the word/words after `";"` OR when the words on both sides are the same. For instance, for Peripheral Blood Mononuclear Cells, it picked the first occurrence, whereas for caucasian, it picked the second one because its the perfect match. I really appreciate any help before downvoting.

Comment: try `list(set(my_list))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The second list that I posted is my required output, i.e., the first occurrence or complete match between the words inside a list element separated by a semi colon.

Comment: so you just want unique values?

Comment: @Hackaholic Set doesn't give me what I need.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, but not with set. It should also be case insensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of all full strings and splitted substrings seen and only add what we have not seen to res:

```
l=['Peripheral Blood Mononuclear Cells;peripheral blood mononuclear cells', 'Blood;peripheral blood mononuclear cells', 'Hispanic or Latino;hispanic', 'Black;black', 'Black;black', 'Asian;asian', 'Asian;asian', 'Asian;caucasian', 'caucasian;caucasian', 'caucasian;caucasian', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Seizure;seizures', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Abscess;abscess']
seen = set()
res = []
for ele in l:
    a,b = ele.split(";",1)
    # make sure we don't have not seen the full string nor left/right hand substring
    # or we find exact matches both sides and we don't already have that perfect match added
    if ele.lower() not in seen and not any(x.lower() in seen for x in (a,b)) or a == b and ele not in seen:
        res.append(ele)
    # keep track of all full strings and left/right substrings 
    seen.update([a.lower(),b.lower(),ele.lower()])
print(res)
['Peripheral Blood Mononuclear Cells;peripheral blood mononuclear cells', 'Hispanic or Latino;hispanic', 'Black;black', 'Asian;asian', 'caucasian;caucasian', 'Seizures;seizures', 'Abscess;abscess']
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I include the second condition where there's a perfect match. The output here's missing the 'caucasian' part.

Comment: sorry, yes  I  missed that one sec

Comment: I think I can do it by including if a.lower() == b.lower()

Comment: @dan if a == b but you will get doubles, is that what you want? try the edit

Comment: Using 'or' has given me multiple occurrences of the same element, which satisfies both the conditions, so I said if a==b: then your if statement.

Comment: Oh but now it has excludes hispanic.

Comment: the code I posted gives matches your expected output

Comment: Actually it does. I'm sorry for the confusion. Thank you very much

Comment: No worries, I did not use `a.lower==b.lower` as that would include `'Black;black'` etc.. if a == b checks for identical strings including case.